# SharePoint Claims, populate name field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, user-profile, claims

I am using SharePoint 2010 foundation with a claims provider. I have build a custom claims provider in which I have working properly. My only concern is that I would like to display the users full name in the SharePoint "name" column for the user.

currently I am passing the following to SharePoint:

- Type: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name
- Type: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Email
- Type: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group

Under User Info, the Account shows as i:0ǽ.t|tokenprovider|userID

However, I am passing the users login ID into the Name claim. If I switch this claim to the users actual Display Name, what will happen to the users account. will it switch to i:0ǽ.t|tokenprovider|Display Name? is there a way to change the Name column to another field (such as Display Name) and still have the account as i:0ǽ.t|tokenprovider|userID?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I just faced a very similar situation with a custom membership provider using claims in SP2013.
After a lot of research and POC's, I could not get the Display Name in the people picker and the login name to be decoupled (basically, show a Display Name and generate the auth claims with a username or unique ID).

Hopefully someone may chime in with a way to achieve this, but my answer would be that this is unfortunately not possible.

Here's a link that states this as a limitation (not that it's a blog for a commercial product):
http://www.riolinx.com/en/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=42

Definitely interested in hearing if there's a more optimistic answer than mine.